# Is there a proverb with the meaning never/nobody knows when?

Tags: proverbs

I need a proverb with ironical sense. To answer a "when" question with the meaning never or nobody knows when. for example, in Russian it will be like - когда рак на горе свистнет. I'm interested in something similar in English.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-0)?

Comment: See this https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/318185/what-is-the-equivalent-of-persian-idiom-when-the-reed-blooms.

Comment: Both answers here are implying *never*. Do you mean that to be the implication—or are you looking to express something that *will* happen, you just don't know when?

Comment: Heaven knows...

Comment: You can include the Russian phrase here, but it's also helpful to include the English translation, the non-literal meaning, explaining when and why you use it, and providing an example sentence or dialogue. Here are two examples: [example 1](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/142679/an-idiomatic-expression-for-the-situation-when-a-punisher-in-fact-punishes-himse), [example 2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/100052/is-there-an-english-equivalent-for-the-italian-saying-its-another-pair-of-slee).

Comment: @Em. After fiddling around with Google Translate, I _think_ the correct translation is "when the lobster on the mountain whistles". Or perhaps "crayfish" instead of "lobster". Or maybe even "crab". In any case, I agree that adding the English translation to the question would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the idiom [**when pigs fly**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/when-pigs-fly) is probably the most popular and well-known English expression when it comes to describing the impossibility of something happening in a humorous way. In other words, it's used to describe a situation that is either very unlikely to happen or simply impossible to happen at all. Here's how the Collins English Dictionary defines this phrase:

> If you say 'when pigs fly' after someone has said that something might happen, you are emphasizing that you think it is very unlikely.

Example:

> — When would they be hired again?
>   — Perhaps, as the saying goes, **when pigs fly**.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [**when hell freezes over**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/when-hell-freezes-over) or [**a cold day in hell**](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/cold+day+in+hell.html) (that is, never).

You would use them like

> It will be **a cold day in hell** before I ever trust Jonathan again.
>   I should apologize to Barbara?  **When hell freezes over!**